# How do I set random break times for each resource?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I would like to set a random break time of 2 hours everyday for each resource unit within a resource pool. I was able to add a schedule for break times set to 2 hours from 12 pm - 2 pm, however, I would like that time interval to be randomly selected for each resource everyday. Can anyone help me with this? I'm pretty new to AnyLogic.

Thanks!

AT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using the break setting forcing you to define a schedule (which is not random), use the "failures/repairs" setting instead and apply randomness as below. Note that this may cause more than 1 break in a day, but on average, it will be 1 a day for 2 hrs. Note also that failures behave exactly like breaks functionally.

[image]

You can, of course, also apply your own custom ResourceTask, name it "breaks" and set it up there.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a solution that will ensure that your resources take 1 break per day:

1. Create a variable in your resource agent called timeForNextBreak with initial value uniform(0,22) ... since they take 2 hours break, you want this to happen between 00:00 and 22:00, this also assumes your simulation starts at 00:00
2. Creat a variable in your resource agent called timeRemainingInDay with initial value 24, this also assumes your simulation starts at 00:00
3. create a custom resource task called randomBreak and use it in your resource pool
   [image: randombreak]
   In your randomBreak resource task, complete the data as follows.
   [image]

Comment: I am trying to add another piece of logic which only allows 75% of the resources to have a break within a given day. I think I can just randomly generate a bernoulli random variate with success probability 0.75, then within Task duration, if the random variate is 1, allow the resource to take a break. I tried creating a random variate with bernoulli(0.75) but I keep getting errors. Any idea why?